# Instance generic class in other class

Tags: java, generics, hashmap

I have two class

```
class Key<T extends Comparable<T>> {// used for composite key for HashMap
 private T q;
 private T o;
 @Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    ...
 }

 @Override
 public int hashCode() {
    ....
 }
}

class A<Key,V, T> {
 private LinkedHashMap<Key,V> map;
 public A() {
  ... suppose we instance map and assign some example values for it here.
 }
 public foo (T q, T o) {
  //From two element q and o, I want to instance a object Key k
  //to check whether this key k is exist in the Map or not by using 
  //map.get(key).
  Key k = new Key(q,o);
 }
}
```

But I got this error "Cannot instantiate the type Key" at the line `Key k = new Key(q,o)`?

So why did it get this error and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Key` is being declared a type variable in class `A`.

```
class A<Key, V, T> { ...
        ^ Everything between <> are type variables
```

This means that when you write `new Key`, you are trying to create an instance of "some" class, not necessarily your `Key` class. Because of type erasure, the actual type is not known at runtime.

Assuming you mean to refer to your `Key` class as posted here, simply remove the declaration of the type variable:

```
class A<V, T> { ...
```

Note that you also should not be using raw types:

```
private LinkedHashMap<Key<T>,V> map;

Key<T> k = new Key<>(q, o);
```

Additionally, you need to bound `T` to conform with the constraints on `Key`, i.e. it must be comparable:

```
class A<V, T extends Comparable<T>> { ...
```